# Помогите исправить баг в таск менеджере

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код:

```js
function instruments(){
    triTochki = document.getElementsByClassName('tri-tochki');
    for(i=0;i<triTochki.length;i++){
        let a = triTochki[i];
        a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('displayBlock');
        })
    }
}
function showTasks(arr){
    let a = document.getElementById('css')
    if(a != null) a.remove();
    let s = document.createElement('div')
    s.id = 'css';

    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        let taske = document.createElement('div')
        taske.classList.add('task')

        let tit = document.createElement('div');
        tit.classList.add('title');
        tit.innerText = arr[i].title;
        taske.appendChild(tit);

        let descr = document.createElement('div');
        descr.classList.add('descr');
        descr.innerText = arr[i].desc
        taske.appendChild(descr);

        let bott = document.createElement('div');
        bott.classList.add('bott')
        taske.appendChild(bott);

        let prior = document.createElement('div');
        prior.classList.add('prior');
        prior.innerText = arr[i].prio;
        bott.appendChild(prior);

        let menu = document.createElement('div');
        menu.classList.add('menu');

        let triTochki = document.createElement('div')
        triTochki.classList.add('tri-tochki');
        triTochki.innerText = '...'
        triTochki.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
        bott.appendChild(triTochki);

        let menuVipad = document.createElement('div');
        menuVipad.classList.add('menu-vipad');
        menu.appendChild(menuVipad)

        let arrowUp = document.createElement('div')
        arrowUp.classList.add('arrow-up');
        menuVipad.appendChild(arrowUp);

        done = document.createElement('div');
        done.classList.add('done');
        done.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
        menuVipad.appendChild(done);
        done.innerText = 'done'

        edit = document.createElement('div')
        edit.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
        edit.classList.add('edit');
        menuVipad.appendChild(edit);
        edit.innerText = 'edit'

        del = document.createElement('div')
        del.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
        del.classList.add('del');
        menuVipad.appendChild(del);

    bott.appendChild(menu);
    s.appendChild(taske);
    }
    tasks.appendChild(s);
    instruments()
}
```

```css
.menu-vipad{
    width: 50px;
    height: 58px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="task">
    <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

    <div class="bott">
    <div class="prior">easy</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="tri-tochki">...</div>
        <div class="menu-vipad">
            <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            <div class="done">done</div>
            <div class="edit">edit</div>
            <div class="del">delete</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Когда нажимаеш на `triTochki` меню которое ищет строка `e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('displayBlock');`
должно появиться. Помогите пожалуйста я уже 5 часов пытаюсь исправить.

Я забыл сказать что он просто не находит `nextElement`

Answer (score 0):

Если это все стили которые вы скинули. то вот - добавьте.
Для итерации коллекции используйте Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(
        'tri-tochki'))

nextElement - это у вас class menu. В итоге меняете class menu
В этом class menu у вас class menu-vipad - который вы скрываете в стилях.

```js
showTasks([
   { index: 0, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
   { index: 1, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
   { index: 2, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
   { index: 3, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
   { index: 4, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
   { index: 5, descr: "Some descr", prio: "Some prio", title: "Some title" },
  ]);

  function instruments() {
    let triTochki = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(
      'tri-tochki'));
    for (let i = 0; i < triTochki.length; i++) {
      let a = triTochki[i];
      a.addEventListener('click',
        function(e) {
          e.target.nextElementSibling.classList
            .toggle('displayBlock');
        });
    }
  }

  function showTasks(arr) {
    let a = document.getElementById('css');
    if (a !== null) a.remove();
    let s = document.createElement('div');
    s.id = 'css';
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let taske = document.createElement(
        'div');
      taske.classList.add('task');
      let tit = document.createElement(
        'div');
      tit.classList.add('title');
      tit.innerText = arr[i].title;
      taske.appendChild(tit);
      let descr = document.createElement(
        'div');
      descr.classList.add('descr');
      descr.innerText = arr[i].descr;
      taske.appendChild(descr);
      let bott = document.createElement(
        'div');
      bott.classList.add('bott');
      taske.appendChild(bott);
      let prior = document.createElement(
        'div');
      prior.classList.add('prior');
      prior.innerText = arr[i].prio;
      bott.appendChild(prior);
      let menu = document.createElement(
        'div');
      menu.classList.add('menu');
      let triTochki = document.createElement(
        'div');
      triTochki.classList.add(
        'tri-tochki');
      triTochki.innerText = '...';
      triTochki.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
      bott.appendChild(triTochki);
      let menuVipad = document.createElement(
        'div');
      menuVipad.classList.add(
        'menu-vipad');
      menu.appendChild(menuVipad);
      let arrowUp = document.createElement(
        'div');
      arrowUp.classList.add('arrow-up');
      menuVipad.appendChild(arrowUp);
      let done = document.createElement('div');
      done.classList.add('done');
      done.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
      menuVipad.appendChild(done);
      done.innerText = 'done';
      let edit = document.createElement('div');
      edit.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
      edit.classList.add('edit');
      menuVipad.appendChild(edit);
      edit.innerText = 'edit';
      let del = document.createElement('div');
      del.dataset.index = arr[i].index;
      del.classList.add('del');
      menuVipad.appendChild(del);
      bott.appendChild(menu);
      s.appendChild(taske);
    }
   document.getElementById("tasks").appendChild(s);
   instruments();
  }
```

```css
.menu-vipad{
    width: 50px;
    height: 58px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.displayBlock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks">
  
</div>
```